# Spring Cassandra vs. Astyanax performance

Tags: cassandra, hector, astyanax, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to evaluate the performance of Astyanax and Spring Cassandra. However I did write up a program to measure insertion and read time. It turned out that with large data Astyanax showed up to 600 times faster insertion rate than Spring Cassandra. I believe Spring Cassandra uses datastax driver to communicate with Cassandra though Astyanax uses thrift. Can anyone who have much knowledge about Cassandra client APIs give me more information on their performance analysis? Is anything appearing wrong in my analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Astyanax and the Thrift protocol are deprecated in Cassandra. Netflix, who contributed Astyanax, has ceased all new development in favor of the Datastax Java driver.

SDC* uses the Datastax Java Driver, which uses the latest protocol, and is very fast in the production emvironments I have deployed into.

Without your test, it is impossible to tell you why you are seeing what you are seeing.

Are you testing reads or writes?

Are you using the spring-data-cassandra or spring-cql module?

Are you explicitly setting the ConsistencyLevel in your SDC* tests?

Which methods of the template or repository are you using for your test.

We can perform 10K writes per second PER NODE in a C* cluster using the DS java driver.

Comment: Astyanax and Thrift are not deprecated. As of the time of writing, the last pull request was merged to the Astyanax GitHub project 6 days ago, and the master branch still uses Thrift.

Comment: It looks like this year they finally put out an official statement that Astyanax and Thrift will be deprecated: http://techblog.netflix.com/2016/02/astyanax-retiring-old-friend.html